# При наведении курсора на изображение оно не размывается

Tags: html, css, hover, blur

Я пытаюсь сделать `hover:blur`, мне нужно, чтобы при наведении курсора на изображение картинка размывалась, когда пытаюсь это сделать

```
.portfolio img:hover
```

либо

```
after{
-webkit-filter: blur(10px);
 filter: blur(10px)
}
```

он не работает, почему? Как я могу исправить эту проблему?

Спасибо

```css
.portfolio ul,
.portfolio li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.portfolio li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.portfolio img {
  background-color: #FFFBFC;
  border: 1px solid #FFEBF6;
  border-radius: 28px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.portfolio img:after {
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
}

.descr {
  border-radius: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(230, 0, 126);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.portfolio li:hover .descr {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.portfolio li .my-scale {
  height: 55px !important;
  width: 80%;
  top: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.portfolio li:hover .my-scale {
  top: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="descr">
            <v-btn class="my-scale " outlined itemprop="url" href="{{$product->link}}" rounded color="white">Skonfiguruj zamówienia</v-btn>
           </span>
      <img class="img-desc" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=Foto" alt="Alt">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю вы уже нашли ответ. Если нет просто замените это: `.portfolio img:after {` на это `.portfolio li:hover img{`. Всё!

```css
.portfolio ul,
.portfolio li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.portfolio li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.portfolio img {
  background-color: #FFFBFC;
  border: 1px solid #FFEBF6;
  border-radius: 28px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.portfolio li:hover img{
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
}

.descr {
  border-radius: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(230, 0, 126);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.portfolio li:hover .descr {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.portfolio li .my-scale {
  height: 55px !important;
  width: 80%;
  top: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.portfolio li:hover .my-scale {
  top: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="descr">
            <v-btn class="my-scale " outlined itemprop="url" href="{{$product->link}}" rounded color="white">Skonfiguruj zamówienia</v-btn>
           </span>
      <img class="img-desc" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=Foto" alt="Alt">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Укажите нулевое значение фильтра для изображения и при наведении меняйте с помощью псевдокласса :hover

```
.portfolio img {
  background-color: #FFFBFC;
  border: 1px solid #FFEBF6;
  border-radius: 28px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  filter: blur(0px);
}

.portfolio img:hover {
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Comment: Это не обязательно, т.к. оно и так по дефолту будет нулевым.