# при наведении курсора мыши изображение должно быть размытым и анимация элементов при наведении с кнопкой выдвигается снизу

Tags: html, css, анимация, hover

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мне нужно чтобы при наведении на картинку выдвигалась анимация при который выдвигается кнопка и картинка стала размытой. У меня получилось так что либо картинку размывает и кнопка как то выдвигается тогда когда я убираю мышку. В чем моя ошибка?

```css
.portfolio ul,
.portfolio li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.portfolio li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.portfolio img {
  background-color: #FFFBFC;
  border: 1px solid #FFEBF6;
  border-radius: 28px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0);
  filter: blur(0)
}

.portfolio:hover img {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter .5s linear;
  transition: -webkit-filter .5s linear;
  transition: filter .5s linear;
  transition: filter .5s linear, -webkit-filter .5s linear;
  transition: 0.5s;
  //opacity: 0.6;
  //background: #e6007e;
}

.descr {
  border-radius: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(230, 0, 126);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.portfolio li:hover .descr {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.portfolio li .my-scale {
  height: 55px !important;
  width: 80%;
  top: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.portfolio li:hover .my-scale {
  top: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="descr">
                    <v-btn class="my-scale " outlined itemprop="url" href="{{$product->link}}" rounded color="white">Skonfiguruj zamówienia</v-btn>
                </span>

      <img src="https://us.123rf.com/450wm/jojjik/jojjik1808/jojjik180800077/107381866-picturesque-morning-in-plitvice-national-park-colorful-spring-scene-of-green-forest-with-pure-water-.jpg?ver=6" alt="Alt">
    </li>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [При наведении курсора на изображение оно не размывается](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1174736/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f)

Comment: да, все так в трансформации цвет меняется div прозрачно - розовой в котором видно эту картику но уже размытую

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот это поможет?

```css
.portfolio ul,
.portfolio li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.portfolio li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: max-content;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.portfolio img {
  background-color: #FFFBFC;
  border: 1px solid #FFEBF6;
  border-radius: 28px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0);
  filter: blur(0)
}

.portfolio:hover img {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter .5s linear;
  transition: -webkit-filter .5s linear;
  transition: filter .5s linear;
  transition: filter .5s linear, -webkit-filter .5s linear;
  transition: 0.5s;
  //opacity: 0.6;
  //background: #e6007e;
}

.descr {
  border-radius: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(230, 0, 126);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.portfolio li:hover .descr {
  opacity: 0.8;
  height: 100%;
  width: 450px;
  z-index: 1;
  filter: brightness(0.8);
}

.portfolio li .my-scale {
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="descr">
                    <v-btn class="my-scale " outlined itemprop="url" href="{{$product->link}}" rounded color="white">Skonfiguruj zamówienia</v-btn>
                </span>

      <img src="https://us.123rf.com/450wm/jojjik/jojjik1808/jojjik180800077/107381866-picturesque-morning-in-plitvice-national-park-colorful-spring-scene-of-green-forest-with-pure-water-.jpg?ver=6" alt="Alt">
    </li>
```